# SharePoint Accept Or Reject Events

Tags: sharepoint

Hi all I am not an expert in SharePoint. so i would like to do the following in SP.
When I make a meeting in Outlook, the recipient gets a approve/reject button in the top of the email. I'd like to do a similar thing with SharePoint , when a calendar event is created, an email is sent to the manager so the manager should able to accept or reject the Event. . 
How do i do this in sharepoint ?

Answer (score 0):

You could attach out of the box approval workflow on Calendar list:

Use an Approval workflow
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/use-an-approval-workflow-HA010154425.aspx

Comment: Thank you Madhur for the fast Reply. but i am new to sharepoint and don't have much idea about all the out of box features . so can you please tell me the steps to follow in order to aquire my Task

Comment: Can Anyone help me with my above requirement ? do i need to create work flow ?

Comment: Steps are there in the given link. Nobody is going to spoonfeed you here. Try it and post any question or issue you face on SO